# How to get JSON file from server? (ASP.NET)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, web

I have a simple web application that operates with a set of words using JS. In order to test the main code I just put a needed data in a variable in my script.

```
CONST WORDS = [
    ["Computer", "Ordinateur", "https://www.lifewire.com/thmb/nNDKywb8qvKzhxelVAR95sEHBj0=/768x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/Acer-aspire-x3300-5804ec185f9b5805c2b6b9e6.jpg"],
    ["Function", "Fonction", "http://latex-cookbook.net/media/cookbook/examples/PNG/function-plot.png"],
    ["Server", "Serveur", "https://effortz.com/wp-content/uploads/dedicated-hosting-server.png"]
]
```

Now I need to build a database (already done) and get such data from the server. So, the question is how do I acquire JSON file from the server using JS? I know how to make GET requests, but what should I do on the server to make it response? (or may be there is an easier way to get this data in JS, considering that I already got it from DB and can easy display on the webpage). 
Here is a backend code

```
namespace LFrench
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Words> WordsSet = Words.GetWords("Business");//recieving from DB a set of words, that i need to use in JS
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms

Comment: is `WebForm1` your controller?

Comment: Hi,

If you are using web forms you will need a web method to return your List of words take a look to this post: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/static-webmethod-in-code-behind-webform/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you need to understand is the flow of your request. if you strictly want to do it in the `Page_Loag` event then I suppose you will have to make a method in your `Javascript` that will actually accept your data as parameter and then call the Javascript method from the `C# CodeBehind` Assuming that the data in the parameter is in `JSON` format. This method works but is not very efficient.

Other way is, in your `JQuery` side, you should make an `ajax` call  to a `WebMethod` of yours in the `CodeBehind` that will actually send the response in `JSON` format. This is cleaner way of doing it.

Your JQuery should look like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
       method: "GET", accept: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
       url: 'MyPage.aspx/GetDataFromDB', success: function(data){
            console.log('Success Response in JSON: ' + data.d); // notice *data.d*, Calling from WebMethods returns the object encoded in the .d property of the object.
       }, fail: function(err){
          console.log(err);
      }
    });
});
```

And your `CodeBehind` should look like:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetDataFromDB()
{
    var myData = YourDbCall(); // Some method to retrieve data from database
    var body = new 
    {
        Firstname = myData.Firstname,
        Lastname = myData.Lastname,
        Email = myData.Email,
        // Any Other Information
    };
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);
    return json;

}
```

**EDIT**
Here is how your Word Set will be sent back as JSON:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetDataFromDB()
{
    List<Words> WordsSet = Words.GetWords("Business");

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(WordsSet);

}
```

Make sure you have installed `Newtonsoft.JSON` from `Nuget Package Manager Console`. if not you can Open Package Manager Console and run this command:

```
PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make json return type method on serverside. Than call it from your get method and do your method on serverside and fill the List and return that list by converting JSON format.